# Embedding Julia in C++

Tags: c++, char, julia, embed

I try to embed Julia as explained in the documentation (https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/embedding/index.html) but can not manage to get it working with chars. I must probably be missing something basic.

When I run the following code

```
jl_function_t *func = jl_get_function(jl_base_module, "uppercase");
char const *julia = "julia";
jl_value_t *argument = jl_box_char(*julia);
jl_value_t *ret = jl_call1(func, argument);
const char *unboxed = jl_string_ptr(ret);
// expecting "JULIA", getting an empty string
```

the variable unboxed is returned empty. jl_box_char seems to expect a pointer since its argument must an uint32_t (https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/24f1316e91de029f71f636db23aced49156b44ad/src/julia.h#L1182).

Note that chars are correctly unboxed when calling:

```
jl_value_t *ret = jl_eval_string("uppercase(\"julia\")");
const char *unboxed = jl_string_ptr(ret);
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: `*julia`is not a pointer. `jl_box_char`"boxes" *one* character. If it would expect a pointer, its parameter would be a pointer, not an integer. You want `jl_cstr_to_string`.

Comment: thanks  @molbdnilo , that's it. The line jl_value_t *argument = jl_box_char(*julia); just has to be replaced with jl_value_t *argument2 = jl_cstr_to_string(julia);

Answer (score 2):

Answer found by @molbdnilo. The following works:

```
jl_function_t *func = jl_get_function(jl_base_module, "uppercase");
char const *julia = "julia";
jl_value_t *argument = jl_cstr_to_string(julia);
jl_value_t *ret = jl_call1(func, argument);    
const char *unboxed = jl_string_ptr(ret); // expecting "JULIA", getting "JULIA"
```